# Uploading file to Moodle using the REST Service core_files_upload

Tags: php, android, web-services, rest, moodle

I am developing an Android app, which will upload content to a user's private files in my Moodle installation using the REST webservice core_files_upload provided by Moodle. core_files_upload takes the following parameters:

```
contextid
component
filearea
itemid
filepath
filename
filecontent
```

The documentation for the Moodle Web Services isn't very detailed so I have pieced together what I can from the Moodle forums and Google searches, but I feel I have come to a dead end.  From examples I have seen that the parameters take the following values:

```
contextid: int - not sure whether this is the userid
component: "user"
filearea: "private"
itemid: 0
filepath: "/"
filename: "filename.jpg"
filecontent: base64 encoding of file
```

I am using my userid as the contextid - I'm usnsure whether this is correct due to lack of documentation.  When I post this I receieve the error:

```
{"exception":"moodle_exception","errorcode":"nofile","message":"File not specified"}
```

I have looked at where core_files_upload is defined in "moodle/files/externallib.php" and this error message is generated when filecontent is not present.

I have tried posting to a test script and I can successfully create the image on the Moodle server based on the base64 encoding eg:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($_POST['filecontent']));
```

Can anyone shed light on why I am being unsuccessful uploading to Moodle?
Is the contextid the userid of the user doing the upload?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so after a bit of further reading and hacking around with code I can confirm that the context id is not the user id, but is derived from the user id.  I have not found any way in Moodle to get the the context id, so I have created my own.  Once I had the context id for the user, the upload worked.

```
define('AJAX_SCRIPT', true);
define('NO_MOODLE_COOKIES', true);

require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/webservice/lib.php');

echo $OUTPUT->header();

// authenticate the user
$token = required_param('token', PARAM_ALPHANUM);
$webservicelib = new webservice();
$authenticationinfo = $webservicelib->authenticate_user($token);

// check the user can manage his own files (can upload)
$context = context_user::instance($USER->id);
$result = array("contextid"=>$context->id);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Hope this helps anyone else who faces the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

- `contextlevel`: The context level to put the file in, (block, course, coursecat, system, user, module)
- `instanceid`: The Instance id of item associated with the context level

If you specify `contextlevel=user` then `instanceid` must be the user id in DB.

Answer (score 1):

maybe can someone post a correct solution.

I will use the Webservice API (core_files_upload) from Moodle and the UserID as Parameter.

```
$fileinfo = array(
'contextid' => null,
'component' => 'user',
'filearea' => 'draft',
'itemid' => 0,
'filepath' => '/',
'filename' => 'sample.txt',
'filecontent' => base64_encode("Hello Word!"),
'contextlevel' => 'user',
'instanceid' => $userid,
);
```

The error is ever "file not specified" - Moodle upload this file to a temp Directory, but then stopped and answer with the error message

Answer (score 1):

After spending three days researching on the moodle core_files_upload function I managed to come up with this optimal solution. Hope this will help someone in future.

```
<?php
 $token = 'Put your token here';
 $domainname = 'Put your app url here';
 $restformat = 'json';
require_once('curl.php'); //Download this file
$curl = new curl;
$params = array(
    'component' => 'user',
    'filearea' => 'draft',
    'itemid' => 0,
    'filepath' => '/',
    'filename' => 'moodle.PNG',
    'filecontent' => base64_encode('/images/moodle.PNG'),
    'contextlevel' => 'user',
    'instanceid' => $userid,
);

/// UPLOAD IMAGE - Moodle 3.10+ and later
$functionname = 'core_files_upload';
$serverurl = $domainname .'/webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . $token .'&wsfunction=' . $functionname;

$restformat = ($restformat == 'json') ?
'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat : '';
print_r($params);
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
$resps = json_decode($resp);

print_r($resps);
printf("\n");
```

Also check this https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=275796
I have tested and it's working as expected.